# Changing the content of .sql file connected to c# application form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .sql file that I want to connect to the c# application form. I have certain labels and textbox in application form. And I want to replace the value of variables in .sql file with values that I input in the textbox.

For example I have declare @name varchar(10) = 'JANNY'
I want to replace Janny with textBox value.

I really appreciate the help regarding this.

Here is the code that I did so far

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sqlConnectionString = @"C:\Jaspreet\Load.sql";
   var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet\Load.sql");
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet\NewLoad.sql", fileContents); 
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add your code

Comment: your code is invisible ;)

Comment: @MUG4N you guys don't understand... That's the code the OP has: `""`

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sqlConnectionString = @"C:\Jaspreet\Load.sql";

            var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet\Load.sql");
            

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Jaspreet\NewLoad.sql", fileContents);

           

        }

Comment: @JaspreetkaurDeol please do post it as a comment

Comment: I am sorry. I m new at stackoverflow. I dnt see any other option. All i can see is the comment button.

Comment: @JaspreetkaurDeol - No problem Jaspreet, I've posted your code into your post. You can do this yourself by clicking the `edit` button at the bottom of your post. [This is a good post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/144930) on formatting code on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I had this other issue too. In my sql file, I have this variable ( declare @ category varchar (10) = '') and I want to replace it with textbox. hw can I do that. I also had other variables like (declare @ department varchar (10) = ' '). But I only want to replace the category variable. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

if you are familar with regex then 
fileContents = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(contents, "[pattern]", "replacementvalue")